# Fetch and display table data in angular and laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display data fetched from laravel api in angular table code is :

```
public function fetchQuestions(Request $request)
{  
  $questions = Questions::where('status',$request->status)->get();
  return response()->json($questions, 200);
}
```

angular code:

```
 questions = [];
  ...
  this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'api/auth/question', formData).subscribe(result  => {
  this.questions.push(result);
```

This does not display any data

i have to use

```
  this.questions.push(result[0]);
  this.questions.push(result[1]);
  ..
  ..
  this.questions.push(result[n]);
```

to push all the data.  How can i push all array data.

and display data using loop

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let img of questions; let i=index">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently pushing an array into an array.
To get the result you want you should just assign the result array to the questions array:

```
...subscribe(result => {this.questions = result})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now getting this error `The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?`

Comment: How are the questions defined? Are they a specific data type? If you do change this.http.post() to this.http.post<DATATYPE[]>(), if not you can use this.http.post<any[]>()

Comment: I have defined it as array   `questions = [];`

Comment: See my edit. You could also define questions as questions:any = []